# Select color of matplotlibs RectangleSelector via rcParams

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I have developed a Python application () with a pyQt GUI and embedded matplotlib canvases. There is a dark and a light theme where the colors are selected via QSS and rcParams for the matplotlib part. However, the rectangularSelector is invisible in the dark theme (black on black) - does anybody know how to select its color via rcParams?

Using @AK_S answer below, I'd like to read the settings from a dict, e.g.:

```
mpl_rc = {
    'toggle_selector.RS' : {'drawtype': 'box',
                            'recttype':dict(
                                      facecolor='green', edgecolor = 'black', alpha=0.2, fill=True)}
}
```

However, I get the error message: `'toggle_selector.RS' is not a valid rc parameter` when doing

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
for key in mpl_rc:
    rcParams[key] = mpl_rc[key]
```

Answer (score 1):

rectprops is the property that you can use.

Example code:

```
toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(plt.gca(), selected_data,
                               drawtype='box', useblit=True,
                               minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                               spancoords='pixels',
                               interactive=False, rectprops = dict(facecolor='green', edgecolor = 'black', alpha=0.2, fill=True))
```

Comment: Thanx for digging up that old topic - still haven't solved the problem. Your approach looks good, however, I haven't managed to import the property as an rcParams. See my edited question.